# How to check an array of strings for a specific character

Tags: javascript

It is necessary to convert the array of strings (it is converted correctly). But it is necessary that the transformations be only with the words ("!", "?", etc. are not necessary). How can this be done with regular expressions?

```
    function pigIt(str){
         letbuffer = str.split(' ');
    
         for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
             if(buffer[i] === /[a-zA-Z]/) {
                 buffer[i] = buffer[i] + buffer[i][0];
                 buffer[i] = buffer[i].slice(1) + 'ay';
             }
         }
    
         return buffer.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ');

}
```

Example string (pigIt('Pig latin is cool !'),'igPay atinlay siay oolcay !')

Comment: _"...with regular expressions?"_ - Why?

Comment: I think this is the easiest way, but if there is another way, I will be glad to help

Comment: `if(buffer[i] === /[a-zA-Z]/)` - This is not how you match something against a regular expression -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Understood, then how can you make a check that only the letters have changed?

Answer (score 0):

Tried your way

```
  function pigIt(str){
         let buffer = str.split(' ');
        let matcher = /[a-z]+/gi;

         for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
             if(buffer[i].match(matcher)) {
                 buffer[i] = buffer[i] + buffer[i][0];
                 buffer[i] = buffer[i].slice(1) + 'ay';
             }
         }
    
         return buffer.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ');

}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool !'))
```